# Learning functional programming

Tags: java, functional-programming

I am mostly a Java developer, this is where I've had the most experience. I want to improve my coding skills so I am looking at learning a functional language.

I don't want it to be too big a leap for me, I don't want to get bogged down in too many unfamiliar things, I'd like to get up to speed as soon as possible.

Can you recommed a language/platform for my first serious look at functional programming?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To be honest, it's the big leap in perspective that makes learning a functional language such a benefit.  I'd say dive in the deep end with the "purest" functional language [Haskell](http://www.haskell.org).

The books [Real World Haskell](http://book.realworldhaskell.org/) and [The Haskell School of Expression](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521644089) are great introductions.

Comment: Not an answer to the original question, but still +1 for "dive in the deep end".

Comment: Another great site that eases one into the ideas of Functional Programming is "Learn You a Haskell for Greater Good": http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters

Answer (score 7):

Try Scala. It's not purely a functional programming language, but it fits right into your toolbox. See [Learning Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/node/1305).

Another option may be [Clojure](http://clojure.org/). That, too, isn't pure FP, but as a Lisp dialect it offers many of the relevant features.

Comment: I will try scala if I find Haskell too much of a leap :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Give yeti a try. This is an advanced ml dialect on the jvm

It is pure functional, integrates nice with Java, is statically typed and is much simpler than ie scala. Has a simpler type-syste, but with full type-inference.

http://mth.github.com/yeti/

Answer (score 2):

Scala was designed with Java and the JVM in mind. Sounds like a nice place to start.

[official web site](http://www.scala-lang.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[FunctionalJava](http://functionaljava.org/) is the best known library to start functional programming in Java.

Answer (score 0):

If you have time to read a book, please try "Effective Java" . It's a very good book for developers.

Comment: I agree with this answer. I have been using the ideas in Bloch's book now for years which has resulted in my Java code strongly using immutability everywhere I can. This single idea substantially shifted my mind to think more towards the functional programming paradigm. And it has substantially eased my now learning Scala.

Answer (score 0):

Several possibilities. Scala runs on JVM, so you can use Java library for a lot of things. I am not a fan, it is way too complex, with lots of syntax to learn.

Scheme is arguably the best language for learning FP, because you can learn the syntax in 30 minutes.

You can also take a look at hybrid languages, like JavaScript, which also have some aspects of a functional language (most importantly, closures), yet keep the procedural tradition syntax.

Comment: I would argue that ultimately, Scheme ends up being as or more difficult to learn than Scala, at least for me. Attempting to use all of Scala when first learning it is of course complex. It's a fantastically intricate and sophisticated language. However, if one just uses Scala in "Java without semicolons" mode and then just takes bite sized chunks to learn new Scala enhanced powers, Scala isn't complex at all. And in fact, it is just about perfect for a skilled Java developer to make small achievable leaps towards _pragmatic_ (i.e. imperfect) functional programming.

Answer (score 0):

As a new programmer of Java,you'd better see the function things of Java area,like *Effective Java*、*the offical API of Java* and many many others.By the way,i like the Oreilly's Book.

Answer (score 0):

As you are very much interested to learn a functional language, I would suggest Ocaml(Objective Caml).  I can suggest you a good book to learn functional programming and lambda calculus.

Types and programming Languages by Benjamin C. Pierce.
http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/